# Solved. Asp Net Core Identity. After publishing each release validation token is not valid

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

Using asp net core 6, razor pages with identity. Everything working perfect. But i have found one small thing that i dont understand.

I am using linux server with kestrel + nginx. After publishing each new release all sended token for validation email going to be failed. I got "VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user.". User should resend new token to validate his email. Why happens this? What should i read?

Also after all each release i should relogin. The configuration is pretty simple.

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    })
    .AddErrorDescriber<LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Link generation

```
var code = await _userRepository.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(User.Id);
        var codeBas64 = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
        var link = _linkGenerator.GetUriByPage(HttpContext, page: "/Account/ConfirmEmail", handler: null,
            new { area = "Identity", code = codeBas64, userId = User.Id }, options: new LinkOptions()
            {
                LowercaseQueryStrings = false
            });
```

Pipelines to publish version is pretty simple

```
pwd
unzip -q '_Build release/Job/YourJobsApp.zip' -d ./tmp
export APPVERSION="$(cat ./tmp/version.json | jq -r '.version')"
mkdir -p /var/www/releases/$APPVERSION
cp -r ./tmp/* /var/www/releases/$APPVERSION
cd /var/www/releases/$APPVERSION
./efbundle-linux-x64 --verbose
rm -f /var/www/publish
ln -sf /var/www/files /var/www/releases/$APPVERSION/wwwroot/files
ln -sf /var/www/releases/$APPVERSION /var/www/publish
systemctl restart test.com.service
echo "Deployed $APPVERSION to /var/www/releases/$APPVERSION"
```

Comment: [Have you checked some related issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29943496/7687666)

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem of generation code. Some stuff related with default token provider. I am investigating source code.

Comment: Solved. Details in this issue https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42837